# Android draw a resized bitmap on another bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I need to draw a bitmap that is resized on another bitmap (scale down one bitmap and then draw it on another).

The code I am using right now is:

```
Resources res = ((Context)(activity)).getResources();
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_report_red);
layers[1] = new BitmapDrawable(getResizedBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)res.getDrawable(R.drawable.report_path_merge_ic)).getBitmap(),10,10));
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(layers[0].getIntrinsicWidth(), layers[0].getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
layerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, layers[0].getIntrinsicWidth(), layers[0].getIntrinsicHeight());
layerDrawable.draw(new Canvas(b));
```

and:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

But the resulting image just shows a fuzzy bitmap that is stretched to the size of the underlying one.

How can I do this? This is the 4th method I am trying...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, I am using a different code completely:

```
Resources res = ((Context)(activity)).getResources();
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_report_red);
layers[1] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.report_path_merge_ic);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 15, 10, 15, 15);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(layers[0].getIntrinsicWidth(), layers[0].getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
layerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, layers[0].getIntrinsicWidth(), layers[0].getIntrinsicHeight());
layerDrawable.draw(new Canvas(b));
```

With emphasis on the line:

```
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 15, 10, 15, 15);
```

This line resized the bitmap on the second layer.